# Iteratively concatenating and labelling data frames in R

Tags: r, loops, dataframe, concatenation

I'm trying to write a for loop in R that reads in a list of filenames from a directory, turns them into data frames, and concatenates them into one large data frame, while adding on an identifier to each data frame so I know which file generated which data came from while plotting. So far, I have a for loop that runs over a function that appends each data frame to an empty data frame I initialise early on, that looks like this:

```
filenames <- list.files(path="reads/metrics", pattern="*.txt", all.files=T, recursive=FALSE, full.names = TRUE)
n= 0
pesto = data.frame(size=character(), fcount= character(),rcount=character(), total = character(), Identifier= character())

concat = function(filename, n){
    dat = read.table(filename, header=TRUE, na.strings="EMPTY")
    dat_i = transform(dat, Identifier = rep((paste("time", n, sep="")), nrow((dat))))
    pesto <<- rbind(dat_i)
}

for (f in filenames) {
n = n+1
concat(f, n)
}
```

So for two examples data frames, that look like this after being read in:

```
> df1 (from file of Time = 1)
         size     fcount     rcount   total
[1,]       1        2           3         5
[2,]       4        1           1         2
[3,]       5        1           2         3

> df2 (from file of Time = 2)
         size     fcount     rcount   total
[1,]       1        3           6         9
[2,]       3        1           5         6
[3,]       5        1           2         3
```

The desired output would look like,

```
> pesto
         size     fcount     rcount   total    Identifier
[1,]       1        2           3         5        time1
[1,]       1        3           6         9        time2
[2,]       3        1           5         6        time2
[2,]       4        1           1         2        time1
[3,]       5        1           2         3        time1
[3,]       5        1           2         3        time2
```

Instead, my output is just df2, but labelled!

So far in debugging I've asked the function to print(n) to make sure I was iterating in the loop correctly and it gave me the correct output:

```
[1] 1
[1] 2
```

I'm at a complete loss on getting this to work - concatenating the files by hand is a pain!

Comment: You're `rbinding` `dat_i` with nothing, the simplest solution would be `pesto <<- rbind(pesto, dat_i)`.

Comment: THAT WAS IT!!!!!!!!!! THANK YOU SO MUCH.

Comment: Wait, I have what might be a better answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do without `for` loops, by using `lapply`. (I know that `*apply` functions are loops in disguise, but they're usually considered better `R` code.)

```
files_list <- lapply(filenames, read.table, header=TRUE, na.strings="EMPTY")
pesto <- lapply(seq_along(files_list), function(n){
                x <- files_list[[n]]
                x$Identifier <- paste0("time", n)
                x
            })
pesto <- do.call(rbind, pesto)
pesto <- pesto[order(pesto$size), ]
pesto
```

Comment: This is very helpful, and a cleaner way of doing things. Thank you!